# How to set attach file size value to progressBar1.Maximum

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

i am creating attached file email sending application, in my application i want to set progressbar1.maximum value as file size value. please tell me how to set attach file size value to progressBar1.Maximum c#/.net

Comment: That reminds me of: "I have created a revolutionary AI from first principles! Also, can anyone tell me how to draw coloured dots on the screen?"

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles if questions should include tags in their titles.  The answer is "No".

Comment: What have you tried?  Where exactly are you stuck?  What does the code that reads the file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question you wish to set the attached file size to the progressbar's maximum property.

**Try the following:**
Make sure to include `System.IO`

```
const string fileName = "myFile.dat";

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
long holdFileSize = file.Length;

progressBar1.Maximun = holdFileSize;
```

**Refer to the following link to learn how to use the progress bar control.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx#Y700

**This link will introduce you to the `FileInfo` Class:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Dayan told us you can create, it will be working.
But why You want to set to progress bar the file length, in bytes it will be really great number, What if you set the progress bars maximum value to the 100, after that you'll check how many percentage you need to change:

```
int uploadedBytes =  getUploadedBytes();
progressBar1.value = (uploadedBytes/fileSize) * 100;
```

this will be enough.